# Invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ while taking std::set element address

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting following error  `error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’`
Following is my program

```
#include <set>
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::set<int> intSet;
    intSet.insert(1);
    intSet.insert(2);
    intSet.insert(3);
    intSet.insert(4);
    intSet.insert(5);

    int *pAddress = &(*(intSet.find(4)));
}
```

I want address of the element in the `std::set` , This code does not give any compilation error with Microsoft compiler but `g++` is giving this compilation error.

Comment: The elements of std::set are constant, in your case constant integers. what MS compiler are you using?

Comment: It's bug in VS2005 which allow std::set to be modified.

Comment: @cpx: Actually, the bug is in GCC; it's valid to modify the set elements as long as you don't affect the ordering. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14410) and [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/lwg-defects.html#103).

Comment: (Or at least it was valid in C++03. The rules have changed in C++11.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because each element of `std::set` is stored as `T const`, and the implementation has a reason to do so.

Since `std::set` contains exactly a single copy of a value. It has to make it *immutable*, otherwise, one can change  it's value to something which already exists in the set.

Even if the elements were *mutable*, you would not be able the change the value, because `std::set::find` is a `const` member function, and therefore in this function `intSet` is *immutable* and effectively each elements would become *immutable* as well, including the *iterator* which it returns, and through which you *may* change the value at the call-site.

The only want to take the address is this:

```
int const *paddress =  &(*(intSet.find(4))); //const int* is same as int const*
```

Don't use `const_cast` though,

```
//DANGEROUS - DONT DO IT
int *paddress =  const_cast<int*>(&(*(intSet.find(4)))); //will compile, 
                                                       //but it is dangerous!

//you might accidentally write
*paddress = 10; //undefined behaviour, 
                //though the compiler will let you write this
```

Comment: Since I just need address of the element, would it be ok to typecast to non-cast

Comment: @Avinash: I added more stuffs to my answer.

Comment: Set elements are stored as `T`, not `T const`, and may be modified as long as you don't affect the ordering. GCC's behaviour, while safer, is nonconformant.

Comment: (Actually, GCC's behaviour is allowed by C++11; it looks like I need to update my knowledge)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Can you add a pointer as to where in C++11 it allows the key type to be a `const T`? I just read over the `std::set` description in N3290 and it uses `typedef Key value_type;` (no const)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: it doesn't allow the key type to be `const T`, but it does state that keys are immutable (23.2.4/5), and that `iterator` is a constant iterator, which may or may not be the same type as `const_iterator` (23.2.4/6).

Answer (score 1):

GCC [defines](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14410) `set::iterator` to be `set::const_iterator`, preventing you from binding a non-`const` reference or pointer to the result of `set::find()`. This behaviour is allowed by C++11 (which states that keys are immutable, and that `set::iterator` is a constant iterator), but was incorrect in C++03.

In C++03, you shouldn't modify the elements of a set since that can break the ordering of elements within it. In some cases, you might want to - if the type is a class, and only some members are used to define the ordering, then it was valid to modify other members. The C++03 standard allows this, but you must be careful not to modify the order as that will give undefined behaviour. In C++11, this isn't allowed, and the implementation may prevent this.

In your case, you can't legally modify the value at all, so you can fix your code for C++11, and also improve its safety, by binding to a pointer-to-const.

```
int const *pAddress = &(*(intSet.find(4)));
```

Comment: Which standard allows this, because in n3225 associative container requirements it is quite clear: "For `set` and `multiset` the value type is the same as the key type. ... Keys in an associative container are **immutable**." and "For associative containers where
the value type is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are **constant iterators**. It is
unspecified whether or not iterator and const_iterator are the same type." - It is even mentioned in the bug report discussion that GCC is considered conforming.

Comment: @UncleBens: I was looking at C++03, which doesn't have those clauses, but does specify that `iterator` is an "iterator type pointing to `T`" for all containers. I'll update my answer for C++11.

Answer (score 0):

The values of the set are meant to be immutable so that the class can guarantee that all of the elements are unique.  Giving you a non-`const` pointer would make it too easy for you to change the value, which would break the design of the set template class ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8wh7665(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8wh7665%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

You should change the last line to have a "const" in front of it like so:

```
const int *pAddress = &(*(intSet.find(4)));
```

FYI: Your code gives an identical compilation error in Visual Studio 2010.